# An observation on Non-Trivial Zeros of Riemann Zeta Function.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I observed this property in month of July this year but unable to design a mathematical proof or mathematical way to state my observation. I need help to state this property.

We know that for certain values of 'b' in **s = 1/2 + ib** , ζ(s) = 0.

When I observed most of the values of 'b' [here](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/zeta_tables/zeros1)

I found that most of the primes are related to these values of 'b' in there square forms like:

```
    Property:    [b] = p^2        {where 'p' is a prime number and [b] is the Box Function}
```

**example:** b = 841.0363...

```
    so,         [841.0363...] = 29^2
```

below **200** there are only **6 primes** which are not following the this above property.

**I am searching a formula or a program to find out all those primes which follow above property but till now I didn't got any solution. I am also not good in programming please help me in this problem.**

Comment: The relationship between the primes and the zeta zeros is given by [Riemann's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Exact_form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $n$th zeta zero has $b(n) \sim 2\pi n/W(n/e)$, where $W$ is the Lambert function. The Lambert function grows as roughly the logarithm of its argument, so we see that the zeta zeroes get denser as $n$ increases, and at $n \approx 10^4$, their imaginary parts should start hitting every integer. This turns out to be the case, as the last square of a prime it misses is $103^2 = 10609$.

We can also estimate the probability of each square of a prime not having a zeta zero near it. The density of zeta zeroes is $W(n/e)/(2\pi)$, so we expect each square of a prime to not be near a zeta zero with probability $1 - W(p^2/e)/(2\pi)$. Summing this over all primes where this value is positive, we get an expected count of $7.7$, which is reasonably close to the actual value of 6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but are you sure that after n=10^4 their imaginary part start hitting every integer. If yes then please tell me where I can see its proof.

Comment: @AdarshKumar My statement is probably a little too strong, but it is known that there is *some* $n$ after which $[b(n)]$ hits every integer. It is also known how to count the number of zeros with imaginary part less than $b$, with formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Location_of_the_zeros). Keeping only the dominant terms and inverting gives my estimate in the answer. It is possible there are integers missed that are significantly larger than $10^4$, but prime squares have very low density at large $n$, making them unlikely to be counterexamples anyways.

Comment: so it means that after some n which you say that will surely exist after which b(n) hits every integer than it is also possible all primes whose square is greater than n also exist . So my property is true till infinite primes. ??

Comment: Yes, this property will hold for all sufficiently large primes. Though since this is true because it holds for all sufficiently large integers, of which primes are a subset, I'm not sure how much this tells us about primes.

Comment: ok thanks a lot to giving your time to solve my problem.

Comment: I checked on the website http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/zeta_tables/zeros1 and found that after 10^4 its not necessary that [b(n)] hits every integer. Now do you still agree on your answer??